# How to send a table in an email in Google Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I've been trying to create a script sending a cell array as a table (keeping formatting) however after hours and circa 30 variations of the code tested I keep on running into a wall...

So far I either:
1. Get an empty email
2. Get an email with all my data but no formatting (all numbers one after the other instead of a table)
3. The table written as HTML code in the email instead of the table itself.
4. An email with [Object] written as the message

I get result 2 by using this code:

```
  var conv = SheetConverter.init(ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
                                 ss.getSpreadsheetLocale());
var html = conv.convertRange2html(dataRange);
```

And finally my last try which was again unsuccessful but seemed promising was the below. My current issue with this one I believe is that the function sendEmail isn't calling getHtmlTable which is above it:

```
function getHtmlTable(range){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  startRow = "6";
  startCol = "B";
  lastRow = "18";
  lastCol = "E";

  // Read table contents
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B6:E18");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // Get css style attributes from range
  var fontColors = dataRange.getFontColors();
  var backgrounds = dataRange.getBackgrounds();
  var fontFamilies = dataRange.getFontFamilies();
  var fontSizes = dataRange.getFontSizes();
  var fontLines = dataRange.getFontLines();
  var fontWeights = dataRange.getFontWeights();
  var horizontalAlignments = dataRange.getHorizontalAlignments();
  var verticalAlignments = dataRange.getVerticalAlignments();

  // Get column widths in pixels
  var colWidths = ["10"];

  // Get Row heights in pixels
  var rowHeights = ["10"];

  // Future consideration...
  var numberFormats = dataRange.getNumberFormats();

  // Build HTML Table, with inline styling for each cell
  var tableFormat = 'style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:center" border = 1 cellpadding = 5';
  var html = ['<table '+tableFormat+'>'];
  // Column widths appear outside of table rows
  for (col=0;col<colWidths.length;col++) {
    html.push('<col width="'+colWidths[col]+'">')
  }
  // Populate rows
  for (row=0;row<data.length;row++) {
    html.push('<tr height="'+rowHeights[row]+'">');
    for (col=0;col<data[row].length;col++) {
      // Get formatted data
      var cellText = data[row][col];
      if (cellText instanceof Date) {
        cellText = Utilities.formatDate(
                     cellText,
                     ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
          'EEE, MMM dd YY'); ///          'EEE, MMM dd - h:mm a');
      }
      var style = 'style="'
                + 'color: ' + fontColors[row][col]+'; '
                + 'font-family: ' + fontFamilies[row][col]+'; '
                + 'font-size: ' + fontSizes[row][col]+'; '
                + 'font-weight: ' + fontWeights[row][col]+'; '
                + 'background-color: ' + backgrounds[row][col]+'; '
                + 'text-align: ' + horizontalAlignments[row][col]+'; '
                + 'vertical-align: ' + verticalAlignments[row][col]+'; '
                +'"';
      html.push('<td ' + style + '>'
                +cellText
                +'</td>');
    }
    html.push('</tr>');
  }
  html.push('</table>');

  return html.join('');
}


  function sendEmail() {
  // Fetch email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B1");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues(); 
  // Send Email.

var message = getHtmlTable;
var subject = 'Test 34';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

If anyone can help it would be extremely appreciated :) it's driving me nuts

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about "[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and "[how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)". This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I found a better way of doing it however I still have a formatting issue. The code now looks like the below but I can't find how to make the background of the cell and the format of the numbers vary depending on what's each cell's format is in the sheet:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of pushing the html code into an array, join the new strings in the same variable. Also, use `htmlbody` as your email body. Notice the variable `table` in the `for` loops:

```
function createTable(data){ 
  var cells = [];
  //This would be the header of the table
  var table = "<html><body><br><table border=1><tr><th>Column A</th><th>Column B</th><th>Column C</th><th>Column D</th><th>Column E</tr></br>";

  //the body of the table is build in 2D (two foor loops)
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      cells = data[i]; //puts each cell in an array position
      table = table + "<tr>";

      for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++){
          table = table + "<td>"+ cells[u] +"</td>";
      }
  table = table + "</tr>"
  }

  table=table+"</table></body></html>";
  


  //Send the email:
 MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "example@mail.com", 
    subject: "Example",
    htmlBody: table}); 

}
```

More information about MailApp and htmlbody [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app).

Answer (score 4):

Anyone who is trying to use Jescanellas's answer, please note that there is a small correction that needs to be made:

```
  //the body of the table is build in 2D (two for loops)
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    cells = data[i]; //puts each cell in an array position
    table = table + "<tr>";

      for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++){
          table = table + "<td>"+ cells[u] +"</td>";
      }
    table = table + "</tr>"
  }
```